# 2D N-BODY SOFTWARE

Tags: resource-recommendations, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, software

When I had a Mac back at JPL in the 80's, I had software that allowed me to enter the mass and X, Y velocity vectors for a number of bodies. It was fun to play with. Is there anything like that out there now? I've seen N-body software for 3D but I really wanted to play with 2D. Much easier to visualize.

Comment: You can play with [this web application](http://phet.colorado.edu/sims/my-solar-system/my-solar-system_en.html), which has a limited user interface. Another option that comes to mind is [Algodoo](http://www.algodoo.com/), which can used to model all kinds of physics in 2D.

Comment: I made this [crude 2D Java App](http://cuug.ab.ca/kmcclary/). I read somewhere that there were stable bands in the asteroid belt at 3.04 and 3.40 AU due to resonances with Jupiter and Saturn. So I made [this model](http://cuug.ab.ca/kmcclary/ORRERY/gap.html) with just Jupiter and Saturn and some red and blue asteroids in the stable bands plus white asteroids in an orbit in between. You can see (after a few orbits) what happens to the white asteroids. I would like to see an application that makes it easier to do this sort of experiment. (My app will probably not be there after Aug 2016.)